# VBA generating custom hash total

Tags: excel, hash, vba

With excel macro (VBA), I need to generate hash total for a series of strings. My current function cant output the correct result.

How to derive the hash total is as such:

1. Subtract the first 11 characters of originating account from the
   first 11 characters of each receiving account.

   - If the account number is less than 11 characters, pad `0` on the right.
   - If the
     account number has an alphabet, convert the alphabet to `0`.
   - Derive the value for each receiving account. Take the absolute value, that
     is, ignore the negative sign.
2. Add the absolute values
3. Take the first 11 character of the result. If the result is less
   than 11 characters, pad with `0` on the left.

This is what I have now:

```
Function cleanString(text As String) As String
    Dim output As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c 'since char type does not exist in vba, we have to use variant type.

    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        'With Sheet2
        MsgBox (i)
        c = Mid(text, i, 1) 'Select the character at the i position
        If (c >= "a" And c <= "z") Or (c >= "A" And c <= "Z") Then
            output = output & "0" 'add the character to your output.
        Else
            output = output & c 'add the replacement character (space) to your output
        End If
        'End With
    Next
    cleanString = output
End Function


Function generateHash(LastRows As Long) As Double
    Dim output As Double
    'Dim c 'since char type does not exist in vba, we have to use variant type.
    Dim Orig As String
    Dim AccNo As String
    Dim temp As Long

    Orig = Left(Range("B3") & String(34, " "), 34)

    For LastRows = 9 To LastRows
        With Sheet2

            AccNo = Left(.Cells(LastRows, 5) & String(11, " "), 11)
            AccNo = cleanString(AccNo)

            temp = Abs(AccNo - Orig)

            output = output + temp
            'MsgBox (output)     
       End With
    Next

    generateHash = output
End Function
```

These are the 26 sample strings, which should produce the hash total of "31341437052"

```
0039002572
0039002580
0030015769
0030016412
0259001090
0259001111
0039002637
0100703387
0100703395
0100703425
0100703433
0100703441
0100703450
0100703468
0100703476
0100703484
0011227958
0011228946
951382892
951700711
301402570
402705981
0030001620
0036001622
111111111
222222222
```

Comment: How is the code in causing errors? on which line does it error?

Comment: There are no errors. The output hash total has to equate to 31341437052 with the 26 sample strings. It's showing some other figures now.

Answer (score 0):

ok. so i figure out it was just some parameters that i was missing.

This convert any alphabet in the string to "0"

```
Function cleanString(text As String) As String
Dim output As String
Dim i As Integer

Dim c 'since char type does not exist in vba, we have to use variant type.
For i = 1 To Len(text)
'With Sheet2
'MsgBox (i)
    c = Mid(text, i, 1) 'Select the character at the i position
    If (c >= "a" And c <= "z") Or (c >= "A" And c <= "Z") Then
        output = output & "0" 'add the character to your output.
    Else
        output = output & c 'add the replacement character (space) to your output
    End If
    'End With
Next
cleanString = output
'MsgBox (cleanString)
 End Function
```

This start the hash function

```
Function generateHash(LastRows As Long) As Double

Dim output As Double
'Dim c 'since char type does not exist in vba, we have to use variant type.
Dim Orig As String
Dim AccNo As String
Dim temp As String
Dim lCounter As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long

'Find the last row that contains data
With Sheet2
    lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
'Take the original string and making sure there are only 11 characters
Orig = Left(Range("B3") & "00000000000", 11)

  'Starts from row 9 
  For lCounter = 9 To LastRows
    With Sheet2


     'Ensuring only 11 characters
     AccNo = Left(.Cells(lCounter, 5) & "00000000000", 11)
     'Clean the string of any alphabet 
     AccNo = cleanString(AccNo)
     'Take the absolute diff of 2nd and 1st string 
     temp = Abs(AccNo - Orig)

     output = output + temp

     'MsgBox (output)

   End With
Next

generateHash = output

End Function
```